# reading a key from project.clj

Tags: clojure

I want to include a key/value in my project.clj, which can then be read from my app. Any ideas how to do it ?

This is for specifying the location of the config file. That is the only part which is hardcoded in the app, and would like to place that as value in the project.clj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without traversing the directory paths yourself and opening the file it's not possible, none the less I don't think that's something you should be doing.

Depending on your deployment strategy your `project.clj` may not even be present when your application is run, think `lein uberjar`.

Even if you're deploying to Heroku where you push everything you have [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) you can read from your program as the suggested approach.

`project.clj` is to be read by `leiningen` to decide how to build your program.

I've used Heroku config vars in the past, proprietary configuration files or even environment variables but think `project.clj` as building instructions, not particular need to reuse when running.

Even [pallet has its own separated file](http://palletops.com/doc/reference/0.8/project-configuration/) for *deployment* rules.